# Return Code Equivalent in Object Oriented Programming

Tags: java, c, oop

As you know, an exit code, or sometimes known as a return code, is the code returned to a parent process by an executable. we can define our return codes something like this:

```
/*url_constants.h*/
int URL_VALID=10000;
int URL_INVALID=-10001;
int URL_HAS_NOT_QUERY_STRING=-10002;
int URL_HAS_NOT_VALID_QUERY_STRING=-10003;
```

and then use them within a function:

```
/*URLParser.c*/
#include <url_constants.h>
int parse_url(const char* url){

    if(UrlIsNotValid(url))return URL_INVALID;
    else if(UrlHasNoQueryString(url))return URL_HAS_NOT_QUERY_STRING;
    else if(UrlQueryIsNotValid(url))return URL_HAS_NOT_VALID_QUERY_STRING;
    return URL_VALID;
}
```

In the above code, "parse_url" function will return an integer which tells us the state of the execution. **modern languages are implement this with an enumeration type. but I don't want to use enums.**

```
/*URLParser.c*/
#include <url_constants.h>
int parse_url(const char* url){

    if(UrlIsNotValid(url))return URL_INVALID;
    else if(UrlHasNoQueryString(url))return URL_HAS_NOT_QUERY_STRING;
    else if(UrlQueryIsNotValid(url))return URL_HAS_NOT_VALID_QUERY_STRING;
    return URL_VALID;
}
```

Now, I'm wondering what is the best way to implement this in object oriented flavor. I know that we can transfer the codes above into an object oriented language such as java, but if we don't want to use above method, how can we tackle to it in an object oriented language.
I think one of the ways to convert the above code to an object oriented syntax like java is to define a base class like this:

```
public class URL_STATES{

}
```

after that we can create a class for each return code which inherits from the `URL_STATES` class:

```
public class URL_VALID : URL_STATES{

}
public class URL_INVALID : URL_STATES{

}
public class URL_HAS_NOT_QUERY_STRING : URL_STATES{

}
public class URL_HAS_NOT_VALID_QUERY_STRING : URL_STATES{

}
```

so we can re-write the `parse_url` in java smoething like this:

```
URL_STATES parse_url(String url){

    if(UrlIsNotValid(url))return new URL_INVALID();
    else if(UrlHasNoQueryString(url))return new URL_HAS_NOT_QUERY_STRING();
    else if(UrlQueryIsNotValid(url))return new URL_HAS_NOT_VALID_QUERY_STRING();
    return new URL_VALID();
}
```

But I think above classes are not necessary. What is your idea about converting the above c code into java ?

What do you think about [*State* design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)?

Comment: classes here seems overdesign, but first of all, what do you plan to do with the return value? if you just put a log an make the program fail, a basic string or exception would do the trick. If you plan to do something else, mabe this function should be a factory on the something else.

Comment: *"modern languages are implement this with an enumeration type"* - Java, being a fairly modern language, has enums too.  (And constants, as in your original example.)  *"but I don't want to use enums"* - Why not?  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @OznOg, How can factories help us in this way ?

Comment: @David, I want to think more wider, such as state design pattern

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid: Well, for the objects being returned to implement that pattern then the example you're already using is exactly how you'd do that.  Your `URL_STATES` class and sub-classes simply haven't implemented their behavior yet.  So they *look* superfluous, because you haven't finished building them.  But then if you already know that you want to return a class which implements a base type or interface, and you already demonstrate how to do that, then it's still not clear to me what you're asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I maybe misunderstanding your question , but I think you can use Enums in Java directly. Something like:

```
 public enum UriStatusMessages {
    URL_VALID(10_000),
    URL_INVALID(-10_001),
    URL_HAS_NOT_QUERY_STRING(-10_002),
    URL_HAS_NOT_VALID_QUERY_STRING(-10_003);

    private final int value;
    private UriStatusMessages(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(value);
    }
}
```

====
This can be used for your function(s). I do not see the need of enforcing an inheritance model here.

Comment: As the author mentioned in the comments, this (simple and in my humble opinion satisfying) solution doesn't allow implementing the state design pattern. Including a functional interface as a parameter might work in the first place, but might lead to unreadable code when the actual logic becomes more complex.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, it's nice that you want to approach the problem object-oriented, but in every project and every fiction, these return codes will be different. just creating a class for a simple return code and inheritance can turn the project into a garbage dump of aimless classes.
return values are used to manage the status of transactions.
Generally, it is defined and used in enum structure in professional systems. It prevents error coding and provides easy status control with standard turns. So what you need is the public static enum structure that is accessed by the whole project.